# Rotate image Jquery help, pls fiddle my jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to allow users to rotate image, but no matter what it just does not seem to work. I have the image drag/drop/resize working perfectly, the rotate just does not want to work correctly.

Please have a look and let me know how I can fix this. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/JDzWD/

CODE:

```
$(function(){  
 //Make every clone image unique.  
   var counts = [0];
    var resizeOpts = { 
      handles: "all" ,autoHide:true
    };    
   $(".dragImg").draggable({
                         helper: "clone",
                         //Create counter
                         start: function() { counts[0]++; }
                        });

$("#dropHere").droppable({
       drop: function(e, ui){
               if(ui.draggable.hasClass("dragImg")) {
     $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
   //Pointing to the dragImg class in dropHere and add new class.
         $("#dropHere .dragImg").addClass("item-"+counts[0]);
             $("#dropHere .img").addClass("imgSize-"+counts[0]);

  $("#dropHere .img").addClass("mainTarget-"+counts[0]);
   $("#dropHere #rotate").attr("id", "target-"+counts[0]);
    $("#dropHere .imgSize").attr("id", "mainTarget-"+counts[0]);


   //Remove the current class (ui-draggable and dragImg)
         $("#dropHere .item-"+counts[0]).removeClass("dragImg ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging");

$(".item-"+counts[0]).dblclick(function() {
$(this).remove();
});     
    make_draggable($(".item-"+counts[0])); 
      $(".imgSize-"+counts[0]).resizable(resizeOpts);  
       }

       }


      });


var zIndex = 0;
function make_draggable(elements)
{   
    elements.draggable({
        containment:'parent',
        start:function(e,ui){ ui.helper.css('z-index',++zIndex); },
        stop:function(e,ui){
        }
    });
}    



   });


//Allow image to be rotated.
var dragging = false;

$(function() {    
    var target = $('[id^=target-]');
    var mainTarget = $('[id^=mainTarget-]');
    var offset = mainTarget.offset();
    target.mousedown(function() {
        dragging = true
    })
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        dragging = false
    })
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if (dragging) {

            var center_x = (offset.left) + (mainTarget.width()/2);
            var center_y = (offset.top) + (mainTarget.height()/2);
            var mouse_x = e.pageX; var mouse_y = e.pageY;
            var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
            var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 120;    
            mainTarget.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-moz-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            mainTarget.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-webkit-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            mainTarget.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-o-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            mainTarget.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-ms-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
        }
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="dragImg"><img class="img" src="http://www.thumbshots.com/Portals/0/Images/Feature%20TS%201.jpg">
     <span id="rotate">Rotate</span></img>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#dropHere {
    width:400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: dotted 1px black;

}
```

Comment: Also, instead of implementing rotation by yourself, you should consider [jQuery rotate plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)

Comment: @PatrickEvans those elements dont exist from the start but are created dynamically

Comment: @PatrickEvans - When I drag the image into the box, and check in firebug, it shows that the cloned element in "#dropHere" has the id "#mainTarget" and "rotate" text has the id "target" but it still does not work.

Comment: Yea i have seen this. For some reason i cannot edit my comment. Will be deleted instead.

Comment: @PatrickEvans -- I have tried to make the changes you suggested, but it still does not work..here is the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JDzWD/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JDzWD/8/)

Change you dropable handler to

```
$("#dropHere").droppable({
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.hasClass("dragImg")) {
            var the_div  = $(ui.helper).clone()
            $(this).append(the_div);

            //Pointing to the dragImg class in dropHere and add new class.
            the_div.addClass("item-" + counts[0]);
            the_div.find('img').addClass("imgSize-" + counts[0]);

            the_div.find('img').addClass("mainTarget-" + counts[0]);
            the_div.find('span').attr("id", "target-" + counts[0]);
            the_div.find('img').attr("id", "mainTarget-" + counts[0]);

            //Remove the current class (ui-draggable and dragImg)
            the_div.find('img').removeClass("dragImg ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging");

            $(".item-" + counts[0]).dblclick(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            make_draggable($(".item-" + counts[0]));
            $(".imgSize-" + counts[0]).resizable(resizeOpts);
        }

        $("#target-" + counts[0]).mousedown(function (e) {
            var item_target = $('.item-' + $(this).attr('id').replace('target-', ''));
            item_target.draggable('disable');
            item_target.removeClass("dragImg ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging ui-state-disabled");
        });


    }


});
```

to your drop handler in order to disable drag while you are rotating. Also change your code in the `$(document).ready()` to the below

```
//Allow image to be rotated.
var dragging = false;
console.log($('[id^=target-]'))
var target = $('[id^=target-]');
var mainTarget = $('[id^=mainTarget-]');
var rotation_target;

$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    if (dragging) {

        var mainTarget = $('.mainTarget-' + rotation_target.attr('id').replace('target-', '')).parent();

        var offset = mainTarget.offset();
        var center_x = (offset.left) + (mainTarget.width() / 2);
        var center_y = (offset.top) + (mainTarget.height() / 2);
        var mouse_x = e.pageX;
        var mouse_y = e.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 120;
        mainTarget.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        mainTarget.css('-moz-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
        mainTarget.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        mainTarget.css('-webkit-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
        mainTarget.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        mainTarget.css('-o-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
        mainTarget.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
        mainTarget.css('-ms-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
    }
});
$(document).mouseup(function () {
    dragging = false
    $("[class^=item]").draggable('enable');
})
$(document).on('mousedown', '[id^=target-]', function () {
    dragging = true
    rotation_target = $(this);
})
```

This code will identify the target for rotation when you mousedown so it knows which image to rotate. It will also enable dragging again after the mouse comes back up so you will be able to move the image around after you have finished rotating

Also add the following css

```
img, span{
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */

/* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

to stop highlighting the text when trying to rotate

Comment: @DGS Thanks for the help, Ill take a few minutes to read and learn what you have done here :) Ill post any questions i have :)

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe how helpful people are on this site. :) thanks alot! I notice much like Patrick Evans code below, the image when rotated cuts off the corners. What cause this to happen, is there any way to prevent this? Or is it how jquery handles rotating images.

Comment: Edited my answer to fix a bug when creating more than one image. You are not rotating the images using jQuery you are rotating them using css transforms. What is actually rotating in this case is the image which is inside a div. Since the div is a rectangle it is trimming off the portion of the image that goes outside its bounds.

I have used your code for the most part but i recommend looking over your decisions to add ids and classes because there is definitely a better way to go about it in this case.

Comment: I see, makes sense, so I guess the best way would be to remove the image container div, this would solve the image clipping issue. Looks like I have some reading to do :)

Comment: Nah you can just change the code to reflect that you want to rotate the div container rather than the image. I have updated my code to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to help, you're a diamond mate :) it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
target.mousedown(function() {
    dragging = true
})
```

is being called too soon, it gets executed before the element has been created in the drop area. You need to use `.on`

```
$(document).on("mousedown","[id^=target-]",function() {
    dragging = true;
});
```

also `mainTarget` will not hold anything either since the element hasnt been created yet, change the mouse move to:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (dragging) {
        var mainTarget = $("[id^=mainTarget-]");
        var offset = mainTarget.offset();
        var center_x = (offset.left) + (mainTarget.width()/2);
```

Your mainTarget id is also not being set

```
$("#dropHere .imgSize").attr("id", "mainTarget-"+counts[0]);
```

needs to be

```
$("#dropHere img[class*=imgSize]").attr("id", "mainTarget-"+counts[0]);
```

`.imgSize` does not work as the actual class is imgSize-(somenumber), so using `*=imgSize` will select an element with class that has the word `imgSize` in it

Also the rotation of the image will not rotate much as the mouse offset from `target` span doesnt have much a chance to change, much as it moves with the mouse move. One exception is when you near the window edges. You might want to use some other code to determine the degree by which to rotate, or remove the dragging while rotating

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JDzWD/4/)

Comment: I have added the changes you suggested, here is the updated jsfiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/JDzWD/1/ but it still is giving me problems and is not working.

Comment: @n00bInNeed, yea fiddling with it, there are other errors you have in the code

Comment: @n00bInNeed, probably because the answer didnt fully answer your question only partially, though it should now, i updated it with the fix for the other errors and with a fiddle demo

Comment: Thanks, with the updated code, You really know your stuff :) how would I disable the dragging when user is rotating? Also, for some reason it rotates the image it cuts the corners off, what causes this issue?